# How does DispatcherServlet pick between a REST and an MVC handler method?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Suppose I have a Spring MVC (3.2+) application with a controller implementation that looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class OrderController{

    @Autowired OrderRepository orderRepository;

    //"RESTful" method
    @RequestMapping(value="/orders/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody Order getOrder(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
       return orderRepository.findOrderById(id);
    }

    //"MVC" method
    @RequestMapping(value="/orders/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getOrder(Model model, @PathVariable("id") long id) {
       model.addAttribute(getOrder(id));
       return "orderDetails";
    }
}
```

Here I have 2 request mappings that will handle requests for the URI "/orders/{id}". One is "RESTful" because it produces json or xml. The other is traditional MVC because it updates the passed in model and returns a logical view name.

My question is how exactly does Spring (the DispatcherServlet) decide which of these two methods to call? My gut feeling (and the documentation for [Producible Media Types](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-produces)) tells me that it would be based on the incoming request's "Accept" header.

However, this begs another question: how 'strict' is the Accept header matching? Below I am listing a few different request scenarios, how would Spring handle these requests given the above mappings?

### Scenario 1

```
GET /orders/123
HOST: www.example.com
Accept: application/json, application/xml
```

### Scenario 2

```
GET /orders/123
HOST: www.example.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

### Scenario 3

```
GET /orders/123
HOST: www.example.com
Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9, text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
```

(Notice both Scenario 2 and Scenario 3 specify they will accept application/xml... just not 'only' application/xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how exactly does Spring (the DispatcherServlet) decide
>   which of these two methods to call?

As you've guessed, it tries to disambiguate by using the `@RequestMapping`'s other properties.

The [javadoc of `RequestMapping#produces()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#produces--) states

> The producible media types of the mapped request, **narrowing the primary mapping**.
>
> The format is a single media type or a sequence of media types, **with a
>   request only mapped if the `Accept` matches one of these media types**

The handler which is most specific, ie. where most mappping properties are matched, will be chosen. In cases, where ambiguity exists, Spring will throw an exception.

In your three scenarios, since `application/xml` is acceptable, the handler method with the appropriate `produces` will be used.

Comment: Interesting. So considering most modern browsers define 'application/xml' as part of their accept headers (2 and 3 were copied from the default firefox and chrome accept headers); my "MVC" method would not be called if I visit www.example.com/myApp/orders/123 from a web browser?

Comment: @FGreg Your best bet would be to try it. (But, yes, the method with the `produces` will be invoked.) (Note that XML and JSON don't necessarily make it any more Restful.)

Comment: I did verify it behaves as you have explained here. I found that the easiest way to make the "MVC" method fire for browsers was to simply add `headers="User-Agent"` to the request mapping for that method. That way if it's a browser, the logical view name would be returned and a view rendered.